# Get nth digit of a sqrt: getting digits that exceed the double scope

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have this code that takes a `digit` and returns a value of the digit that is in that `digit` position in the `sqrt(2)`:

```
public static int sqrtTwo(int digit)
{
    //1.41421356237…
   double result = Math.sqrt(2.0);

   String resultString = String.valueOf(result);

   if (digit == 0)  {
       return Integer.parseInt(resultString.substring(0, 1));
   }

   if (digit + 1 >= resultString.length())  {
       digit = resultString.length() - 2;
   }

   return Integer.parseInt(resultString.substring(digit + 1, digit + 2));
}
```

But I can only get so many digits by using it. The `Math` class would return a `double` which is limited. I want to calculate a `sqrt` value up to a certain digit, be it a 100th or 500th digit, no matter. How should I do that?

I have found this code, but it looks limited by `double` as well:

```
    static double squareRoot(int number, int precision)
    {
        int start = 0, end = number;
        int mid;

        // variable to store the answer
        double ans = 0.0;

        // for computing integral part
        // of square root of number
        while (start <= end)
        {
            mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if (mid * mid == number)
            {
                ans = mid;
                break;
            }

            // incrementing start if integral
            // part lies on right side of the mid
            if (mid * mid < number) {
                start = mid + 1;
                ans = mid;
            }

            // decrementing end if integral part
            // lies on the left side of the mid
            else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        // For computing the fractional part
        // of square root upto given precision
        double increment = 0.1;
        for (int i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
            while (ans * ans <= number) {
                ans += increment;
            }

            // loop terminates when ans * ans > number
            ans = ans - increment;
            increment = increment / 10;
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: you could use BigDecimal https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: `BigInteger` is enough; no need for `BigDecimal`. `BigInteger` even has a [`sqrt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#sqrt()) method to perform integer square roots in recent incarnations of Java - if you use that, you should only need a few lines of code. The equivalent code in Python would be `math.isqrt(2*100**k) % 10`, to get the value of the kth place after the decimal point of the square root of 2.

Comment: @MarkDickinson `BigInteger#sqrt()` was introduced in Java 9. Do you think the digit-by-digit method can do the trick?

Comment: There is a sqrt in BigDecimal since Java 9 but in earlier versions I had success with Newton's method, Q.V.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The sqrt method of BigInteger only does integer square roots, so it would not be of much use in getting the nth decimal place of a square root.

Comment: I can only use Java 8 for this task ; (

Comment: @DavidConrad On the contrary, it's plenty useful! The square root of 2 is `1.414213562373...`. The *integer* square root of `200` is `14`. The integer square root of `20000` is `141`. The integer square root of `2 * 100^6` is `1414213`. See the pattern? The last digit of the integer square root of `2 * 100^n` gives you the nth decimal place of the square root of 2. For example, using this, I can tell you that the 1 millionth decimal place after the point is a `3`, just by evaluating `isqrt(2 * 100**1000000) % 10` in Python; it takes under 10 seconds to get that result.

Comment: @M.S. Ah, that's unfortunate. In that case using `BigDecimal.sqrt` may be easier, but you'll need to fuss with rounding modes and/or extra precision to be sure of getting the right result. Or you can implement any of the well-known and well-documented integer square root implementations - e.g., the method based on Newton's algorithm (really Heron's method) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "2" in the big decimal constructor is the value of what operation you want to do, the 1000 in the MathContext is how many digits you want to get from it.

so like this is how I would get get sqrt(2) to 1000 decimal places

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal digits = new BigDecimal("2");

    BigDecimal num = digits.sqrt(new MathContext(1000));
    System.out.println(num.toString());

}
```

Comment: You need to be careful with rounding. For example, if you used this to compute the 1001st place after the decimal point, you'd likely get a `1`. But the digits from that point go: `089694...`, so the actual digit in that position is a `0`.

Comment: Didn't know that! So if I wanted to find the 1001st decimal spot would I account for like 1015 digits instead of 1001, and then use that instead to avoid rounding?

Comment: Yes, that's one way, but it's not foolproof: for example, if you happen to encounter a place in the decimal expansion of `sqrt(2)` where there are fifteen `9` digits in a row (and that's guaranteed to happen _somewhere_ in the expansion), then you'd need more than 15 extra digits to avoid rounding errors. Look up "The Table Maker's Dilemma" for more background on this. A better way would be to set the rounding mode to `FLOOR`.